# How to c# programmatically or command line open explorer.exe to the "Recycle Bin"

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

I want a WPF button that will open explorer.exe in Windows 7|8 directly into the "Recycle Bin".  This is because my app erases a lot of files, and I want to provide the user with a quick way to restore files. The command line arguments don't work, possibly because the "Recycle Bin" is a virtual directory. I have tried using "$Recycle Bin". Explorer.exe /root, where a is a virtual file fails. Trying to protect the space in Recycle\ Bin does not seem to work as well.

Here is working code from Scott Powell that I tested and am using.
Thank you Scott@

```
    private void ExploreTrashBin ( )
        {
        String str_RecycleBinDir = String.Format(@"C:\$Recycle.Bin\{0}", UserPrincipal.Current.Sid);
        Process . Start ( "explorer.exe" , str_RecycleBinDir );
        }
    private void TrashBin_Button_Click ( object sender , RoutedEventArgs e )
        {
        ExploreTrashBin ( );
        }
```

Comment: better show us some code

Comment: Thanks to Scott Powell for the above suggestion to use Account Management to recover the SID and open Explorer in the real directory instead of the virtual directory.

Comment: please don't put code in comments, [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28311915/edit) and put code examples there.

Comment: Scott Chamberlain: done

Answer (score 5):

You could execute following command in order to achieve this,

```
start shell:RecycleBinFolder
```

From your C# code you could use,

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("explorer.exe", "shell:RecycleBinFolder");
```

Answer (score 1):

It is already implemented in **Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FileSystem** class in .Net (so C# natively supports the use of [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.filesystem.deletedirectory%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).

This way, you don't need run  <del>shell command</del> : just delete files/folders **programmatically** as if done **interactively** with Windows Explorer!

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO;

FileSystem.DeleteFile(...)
FileSystem.DeleteDirectory(...)
```

[image]

Comment: And don't let the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` namespace put you off. It is perfectly fine to use from C# code.

Answer (score 0):

Recycle Bin is located in a hidden directory named \$Recycle.Bin\%SID%, where %SID% is the SID of the user that performed the deletion.

So based off of this, we can do:
Add a .NET reference to System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement

```
string str_RecycleBinDir = UserPrincipal.Current.Sid;
Process.Start("explorer.exe","C:\$Recycle.Bin\" + str_RecycleBinDir);
```

Should be able to now access the proper Recycle Bin directory based off user account that is running. Working in Windows 7 (tested).

Comment: Works like a charm!          private void ExploreTrashBin ( )
            {
            String str_RecycleBinDir = String.Format(@"C:\$Recycle.Bin\{0}", UserPrincipal.Current.Sid);
            Boolean Sucess=Process . Start ( "explorer.exe" , str_RecycleBinDir );
            }

Comment: I don't like this - you're basing this off an implementation detail of the recycle bin that might change in a future Windows version.

Comment: @Dai I honestly doubt Microsoft would change something like that in a future version. Even if it does change, its a line of code that'd need to be updated, that's it, that's all. A very simple change.